# Foundation in ember cli application using ember.js 2.0

Tags: javascript, ember.js, zurb-foundation, ember-cli

I am working on ember application using ember-cli.

ember version is `"2.0.0-beta.2"`

I am integrating the foundation 5 in application, installed bower package for foundation and also included it in **ember-cli-build.js** file

```
app.import('bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.js');
app.import('bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.offcanvas.js');
```

Now i want to initialize the foundation as

```
Ember.$(document).foundation({
  offcanvas: { close_on_click: true }
});
```

But in `ember-2` they have removed views completely, where should i initialize it?

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally able to fix it.. Thanks to "Taras Mankovski"

Here is the solution https://github.com/embersherpa/ama/issues/8

application.hbs

```
{{#app-canvas}}
  <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>
  {{outlet}}
{{/app-canvas}}
```

components/app-canvas.js

```
import Ember from "ember";
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  didInitAttrs() {
    Ember.run.schedule("afterRender", function() {
      Ember.$(document).foundation({
        offcanvas: { close_on_click: true }
      });
    });
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pasting solution over SO

Comment: Glad to know that it helps someone :)